# SQL Lookup to another table to do aggregation and merge it back to the outer query

Tags: sql, oracle

Query: Being able to do lookup from Table A to Table B and use an aggregation function based on date criteria referencing date fields from Table A with the date fields from Table B.

Scenario:

I have a car table (contains CAR_ID,Car_START_DT,Car_END_DT) and a car_payments table (contains CAR_ID, Car_Payment_DT, Car_Payment_Amt).

For every car in the car table, I would like to do a lookup into car_payments table using CAR_ID and aggregate by counting the number of Car_Payment_Amt records between the Car_START_DT and Car_END_DT (from car table) using Car_Payment_DT.

For my attempt, I created a subquery to COUNT(Car_Payment_Amt) GROUP BY CAR_ID under car_payments table and JOIN it with Car table based on CAR_ID to get the results but realized that the subquery will be taking longer than expected as the data size grow larger.

How can I do this efficiently using SQL? I did a search and people are saying that using correlated query but it has performance bottleneck. Are there any other options?

Comment: You might as well say any query will take longer the more data there is... It's true, but ultimately if you need to get that data, you have to suffer the performance hit. Good news though: most main RDBMSs are designed to find the "best" path to retrieve the data. You've got to help the database though, by adding indexes and keeping the database stats of your table up-to-date, etc. In short, use your aggregated query and index your table(s) appropriately.

Comment: You're possibly missing adequate indexing, for example I'd expect a composite index something like `car_payment(car_id, car_payment_dt)`. Shown the actual query, the table definitions, and the explain plan for running the query.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a simple join

```
select
    c.car_id, count(cp.payment_amt) as pmt_count
from
    car c 
    left join
    car_payment cp on cp.car_id = c.car_id 
        and cp.payment_dt between c.car_start_dt and c.car_end_date
group by
    c.car_id
```

Comment: This will not show the cars without payments within period, and it should if "for every car in the car table ... ..." (mentioned in the Q) means as it looks like.

Comment: @dr ok so make it a left join and only count the payment_amt

Comment: It's not about me but the one that asked a question... @Kurt

Answer (score 0):

You can try it without grouping like here:

```sql
SELECT  c.CAR_ID, 
        (Select Count(*) From payments 
         Where CAR_ID = c.CAR_ID And PAY_DATE Between c.START_DATE And c.END_DATE) "NO_OF_PAYS"
FROM    cars c
```

which with following sample data:

```sql
WITH
    cars (CAR_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) AS
        (
            Select 1, To_Date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('04.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 2, To_Date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('06.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 3, To_Date('03.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('08.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 4, To_Date('03.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('10.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 5, To_Date('05.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('12.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual Union All
            Select 6, To_Date('07.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('14.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') From Dual 
        ),
    payments (CAR_ID, PAY_DATE, AMAUNT) AS
        (
            Select 1, To_Date('01.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 100 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('03.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 100 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('05.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 100 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('06.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 100 From Dual Union All
            Select 3, To_Date('05.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 300 From Dual Union All
            Select 3, To_Date('08.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 300 From Dual Union All
            Select 3, To_Date('11.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 300 From Dual Union All
            Select 5, To_Date('11.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 500 From Dual Union All
            Select 5, To_Date('13.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 500 From Dual Union All
            Select 6, To_Date('06.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 600 From Dual Union All
            Select 6, To_Date('12.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 600 From Dual 
        )
```

... results as

```sql
--  R e s u l t :
--      CAR_ID NO_OF_PAYS
--  ---------- ----------
--           1          2 
--           2          0 
--           3          2 
--           4          0 
--           5          1 
--           6          1
```

Comment: That still has "grouping", it's just implicit. Just because you didn't type it doesn't make it go away, you're using an aggregate function and an implicit equivalent to `GROUP BY NULL` to get a full set aggregate, and embedding it in a correlated subquery means you'll likely just get the same explain plan.

Comment: @MatBailie You could put it that way too, but it's where conditioning not grouping and  with some proper indexing it could be faster...

Comment: Indexing, yes, absolutely. Reforming the query as you have done, no.

Comment: @MatBailie Totals of plan for this: (group)[where] *Rows(37)[41] *Bytes(374)[396] *Cost(174)[80] *Time(::22)[::20] - no indexing no nothing...